# Vimball error, unrecognized character in path

Tags: vim

I have a problem with installing SuperTab from vimball. I get an error:

```
E739: Cannot create directory: C:\Users\Pawe<b3>\vimfiles
```

I guess the problem is the directory name which is `C:\Users\Paweł\vimfiles`. Is there a way to solve it without changing directory name? Btw: I have `set encoding=UTF-8` in my vimrc.

**Edit:**

The way I install it is so: download .vmb file, open it with vim (using context menu: 'edit with vim') and then I write `:so %`. And the error occurs.
Using `:set verbose=20` I get http://pastebin.com/BLaeLzuU (those are things I found interesting).

And here's the wider story. I was trying to install plugins using vimballs, because I failed running plugins with pathogen (identical case as here: https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/issues/110. In fact my output of `:scritpnames` is here: http://pastebin.com/YBTBvsvz). To tell you the truth I even tried to copy folder `plugin` form plugins git repo to my `~\vimfiles`. With no success (they are not mentioned in scriptnames). And so I don't have any clue what is going on. Only that output from vimball tells me that it could be the path name. Other then that, I'm hopeless.

Btw: using Windows 8 if that's a deal breaker.

Comment: Post this question in [vim_use](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/vim_use), you're more likely to get an authoritative answer there since the vimball maintainer reads that list.

Comment: Find out where exactly that `E739` is raised (e.g. with `:set verbose=20`, and post a minimal example (command) to reproduce. That will help in getting an answer.

Comment: Made a little edit. Hope it helps with solving the problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I have renamed the user name and user folder because the directory name was a problem for other aplications too. Here are the instructions: https://superuser.com/questions/495290/how-to-rename-user-folder-in-windows-8